# NodeJS - How do I call separate imports based on 'if' condition for ES Modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, es6-modules, esmodules

Followed a tutorial that uses CommonJS to export/require different keys based on the environment. How do I get it to work with ES Modules import/export?

This was the code he used:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
module.exports = require('./prod')
else {
module.exports = require('./dev')
> }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have to import the functions/components.

```
import Production from "./prod"
import Development from "./dev"
```

Then you can check the condition, and assign the specific function/component to a variable. Finally, you can export it.

```
let defaultExport

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  defaultExport = Production
} else {
  defaultExport = Development
}

export default defaultExport
```

The full code will look like this

```
import Production from "./prod"
import Development from "./dev"

let defaultExport

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  defaultExport = Production
} else {
  defaultExport = Development
}

export default defaultExport
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to do but you can try ternary operator

```js
module.export = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? require(./prod) : require(./dev)
```